# Can this check still be honored?

Tags: paycheck

I recently found in my late husband's files, an uncashed payroll check dated 2/07/90 in amount of $557.74 which he  apparently had overlooked.  He passed in 2012.  Is it even pos-  sible to be remunerated at this late date for money he earned?  The company is still in business.

Answer (score 0):

You could talk to them, but (assuming you're in the U.S.), it's highly doubtful any bank would honor a check from 26 years ago.  Most checks in the U.S. are only valid for 180 days, mainly to help companies and banks keep accounting simple.

I would suggest talking to your late husband's former employer.  Explain the situation and ask if they'd be willing to research it and perhaps honor his memory and contribution to their company by issuing a new check.  They might do it as a gesture of good will.

Are they legally *bound* to do this?  To my knowledge, the answer is no.  The check was issued and never cashed, which is not all that unusual for companies in business for a long time.  A good example of this would be rebate checks, which (you'd be surprised) quite frequently end up in a drawer and forgotten about.  There has to be some closure for the issuing company in its accounting, else they'd have money in their bank accounts that doesn't properly show in their ledgers.

This is an interesting question, though.  I hope others will reply, and perhaps they have a more informed take than me.  I'm going to upvote it simply because I'd like to see this discussion continue.

Good luck!

Comment: This answer is completely wrong, at least in case of a US company.